# Extrapolation attribute values of custom annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I write a spring-boot test and created a custom annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
public @interface IntegrationTest {

    String[] properties() default {};
}
```

As you can see, I've defined the `properties` attribute to have the possibility to override properties like that:

```
@IntegrationTest(properties = {"my.property=value"})
public class MyIntegrationTest {
    // test code here
}
```

I don't have any additional configurations and value of my attribute is automatic put into `@SpringBootTest(properties = )`, that is what I actually wanted to achieve.

But now I'm wondering how it is understood that the value of this attribute should be put in `@SpringBootTest(properties = )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should annotate the `properties` with [`@AliasFor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.0.RC2_to_4.2.0.RC3/Spring%20Framework%204.2.0.RC3/org/springframework/core/annotation/AliasFor.html) as follows:

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
public @interface IntegrationTest {

    @AliasFor(annotation = SpringBootTest.class, attribute = "properties")
    String[] properties() default {};
}
```